# Add a decimals to jQuery Calculator

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out how to add decimal places to this jquery calculator. Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? I know that the .toFixed function needs to be utilized. But where do I put it?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
color:black;
}

</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


         $('.option').click(function(){
         var total=0;

                       $('.option:checked').each(function(){
                       total +=parseInt($(this).val());
                       });

         $('.total').html('$'+ total);
         $('.total').toFixed(2);
         });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>

  <input type="checkbox" class="option" value="200"/>


<div class="total">$0</div>

<div class="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Send" <a href="localonline.com">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use it on `total` not a jQuery object

Comment: $('.option').click(function(){
         var total=0;
         total.toFixed(2);

Is this correct? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just use this :

```
 $('.total').text('$'+total.toFixed(2));
```

http://jsbin.com/UvAfaYOM/3/edit

the toFixed should be applied on a number.

Comment: Royi thanks for the help. It worked, however it negated the $ sign for the total. Any suggestions on what to do to get that back?

Comment: Lol yep simple enough. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @logan713 if that answer helped you and was correct, then kindly check it and mark as a correct answer so others can benefit from it. Thanks.